# Чтение-запись в, из файла

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Задача заключается в следующем.

> Открыть файл, содержащий десять цифр, считать их и показать в диалоге. Создать новый файл, и записать в него сумму этих чисел.

Вопрос заключается в следующем:

1. Как правильно считать цифры из файла для дальнейших операций с ними.
2. Как записывать в файл

Вот что у меня получилось (неполная версия программы, но зато рабочая)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    FILE *fp = fopen("test1.txt", "r");

    if (NULL == fp) {
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл!n");
        return 0;
    }

    char str[24] = "";

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(str, 24, fp);
        printf("%s", str);
        printf("n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    system("pause");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

P.S замучился уже с этой VisualStudio С++: нет никакой информации и примеров задач, а если и есть, то там настолько непонятные символы, что голову сломать можно.

Answer (score 3):

> Как правильно считать цифры из файла для дальнейших операций с ними.

Как и какие цифры записаны в файле? Если через пробел и целочисленные, то:

```
ifstream f("имя_файла.txt", "r"); // открыть файл для чтения
vector<int> numbers; // вектор куда будем записывать считанное
copy(istream_iterator<int>(f), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter<vector<int> >(numbers)); // непосредственно считывание из файла и запись в вектор
```

> Как записывать в файл

Аналогично:

```
ofstream f("имя_файла.txt", "w"); // открыть файл на запись
copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(f, " ")); // непосредственно запись из вектора в файл
```

предполагается, что в векторе `numbers` лежат цифры (хотя если вектор и пустой, то код тоже корректно отработает).

Comment: Не, ничего не пойму copy(istream_iterator<int>(f), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter<vector<int> >(numbers)); ---что это за строка для чего она нужна? В какой вектор мы копируем?

Comment: в вектор ``numbers``. ``copy`` - функция стандартной библиотеки, первый параметр - начала копируемого диапазон, второй - конец коп. диапазона, третий - начало диапазона, куда копируем.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша версия программы считывает строку char, иными словами символы, выводит она их правильно, но складывать не будет, так как распознает как буквенную строку. Лучше всего в данной ситуации считывать функцией fscanf в буфер по одной цифре

```
int A;
fscanf(A[i],"%d",fp);
```

Только почему у вас 24 символа в строку считываются? Затем, когда в новый файл писать будете, открываете его на запись и пишете туда сумму

```
FILE *fout = fopen("test2.txt", "w"); 
int C=0;
for (i=0;i<=9,i++)
C+=A[i];
fprintf(fout,"%d",C);
```

и закрываете файл.

Comment: при этом ваши 10 цифр должны быть записаны черед пробел, пробел отделяет одну %d от другой(запятую может располнать как дробь)

Comment: Не понял куда мне эту строку? В цикл или вместо char? Если ставлю в цикл, то программа выдает 3 ошибки. Или тут в начале нужно все кардинально менять?
 fscanf(A[i],"%d",fp);

Comment: Я понимаю, то что программа считывает это как картинку. Только я понятия не имею как сделать это по другому. Бибилиотеки дополнительные нужны? И при помощи каких функций?

Comment: считате число элементов в файле
int j=0;
while (!feof(fp)) {if (fgetc==' ')j++;}// у вас их 10 как я понимаю, т.е. от 0 до 9

внутри цикла while  добавляете цикл дл массива А for (i=0;i<=9,i++) 
double A[10];
rewind fp;
while (!feof(fp)) { 
for (i=0;i<=j,i++) // для вас аналогично (i=0;i<=9,i++)

        fscanf(A[i],"%d",fp); 
        printf("%d", A[i]); 
        //printf("n"); 
    } 

как то так.

Comment: пардон, там fscanf(A[i],"%d",fp) наоборот указываете кажись, сначала файл, потом буфер fscanf(fp,"%d",A[i])